# Can I use Map Side join in hive if I have 5 tables?

Tags: dictionary, hive

Can I use Map Side join in hive if I have 5 tables, out of which 4 are of 5GBs and one is of 150MB? If yes then how? If not then why not?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this -

```
SELECT /*+ MAPJOIN(c) */ * FROM main_table o 
JOIN smallest_table c ON (o.id=c.id)
JOIN next_table n1 ON (n1.id=c.id)
JOIN next_table2 n2 ON (n2.id=c.id)
```

Map join will be on smallest table. Then join in order of size in descending order.